# LWC :how can i display the list of Objects in a drop down list and when we select an objects it should display it fields

Tags: salesforce, lwc

Lightning web Components to display list of Objects in a drown list. and display fields of selected objects

Answer (score 0):

this is possible using [getGlobalDescribe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#apex_System_Schema_getGlobalDescribe) in Apex side and then [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) on the javascript side.

If you need something already working, you can have a look at the AppExchange market and try to find a solution there.

If you need a development, I suggest to find a developer or hope that someone will have time to give you that for free but this website is more about questions/issues that we try to solve.